# Conditional probability about card picking.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A card is picked at random from N cards labeled 1,2,3,,,,,N and the number that appears is X. A second card is picked at random from cards numbered 1,2,3,,,X and its number is Y.

I am asked to determine the conditional distribution of X given Y=y for all y

I considered every possible case,

For P(X=x given that y=1), given that second card number is 1, X can be any card from 1 to N.

P(X=x given that y=1)= 1

For P(X=x given that y=2), given that second card number is 2, X can not be number 1 card.

So, P(X=x given that y=2)= N-1/N for x>1

And I actually found out the pattern, which gives me

P(X=x given that Y=y) for all y = N+1-y/N .

Is it the right conditional distribution of X?

Comment: "P(X=x | Y=1)=1"?  Do you mean to say that if $x=5$ that P(X=5 | Y=1) = 1 while also P(X=6 | Y=1) = 1, so there is a 100% chance that the value of X is a 5 and also a 100% chance that the value of X is a 6?  Also, I recommend learning to type in $\LaTeX$ because N+1-y/N is ambiguous whether you mean $N+1-\frac{y}{N}$ or $\frac{N+1-y}{N}$

Comment: I guess I did it wrong and trying to figure it out. And (N+1-y)/N is what I meant,

Comment: Could you help me with it, cause its getting confusing

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Probability and the Law of Total Probability to determine that:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y)
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(X=x)\,\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)}{\sum_{k=1}^{N} \mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=k)\,\mathsf P(X=k)}\; \mathbf I_{y\in \{1;x\}, x\in\{y;N\}}
\\
 & = \frac{\frac 1 N \cdot \frac 1 x}{\frac 1 N \sum_{k=y}^N \frac 1 {k}}\; \mathbf I_{y\in \{1;x\}, x\in\{y;N\}}
\\ 
 & = \frac{1}{x (H_N-H_{y-1})}\; \mathbf I_{y\in \{1;x\}, x\in\{y;N\}}
\end{align}$

Where, $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Harmonic Number.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider what $f(x,y) = P(X=x, Y=y)$ is.  Note that for $y>x$ you get $f(x,y)=0$ since it is impossible to have drawn a larger card than exists in the pile.  It should follow quickly that among the remaining values for $y$ given a specific $x$ that the distribution would be uniform.

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0\text{ for }y> x\\ \frac{1}{N}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Indeed, if we do $\sum\limits_{x=1}^N\sum\limits_{y=1}^N f(x,y)$ we get:

$$\sum\limits_{x=1}^N\sum\limits_{y=1}^N f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{x=1}^N\sum\limits_{y=1}^x \frac{1}{N}\cdot\frac{1}{x} = \sum\limits_{x=1}^N \frac{1}{N} = 1$$

as we would have hoped.

Looking at it in a different form, we have the following table:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{N} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  \\
\frac{1}{2N} & \frac{1}{2N} & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{3N} & \frac{1}{3N} & \frac{1}{3N}& 0 & \dots\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{1}{N^2} & \dots & \dots & \frac{1}{N^2} \end{bmatrix}$$

where the $i$th row $j$th column entry corresponds to $f(i,j)$ (i.e. $x=i$ and $y=j$)

So, given that $Y=y$, we restrict ourselves to the $y$th column only.

$P(X=x|Y=y) = \begin{cases} 0 ~\text{ if } x<y\\ \left(\dfrac{\frac{1}{xN}}{\sum\limits_{i=y}^N\frac{1}{iN}}\right)~\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}  = \begin{cases} 0 ~\text{ if } x<y\\ \left(\frac{1}{x\sum\limits_{i=y}^N\frac{1}{i}}\right)~\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$

simplifying further as desired.

Comment: Hi my TA explained that P(X=x given Y=1)=1/N  and                P(X=x given Y=2)=1/(N-1) and it keeps going, is that equivalent to what you ve shown?

Comment: My answer agrees with Graham's answer above.  In particular, P(X=x | Y=1) will depend on what $x$ is.  It is more likely that $x$ will be smaller rather than bigger.  If we were to choose $Y$ before we chose $X$ and we picked $X$ from the numbers $y,y+1,y+2,\dots,N$ then your TA would be correct, but we are picking $X$ first before we pick $Y$.

Comment: To convince yourself of this, take a small example, say, $N=2$.  You have a 50% chance of picking X=1 and a 50% chance of picking X=2.  If you picked X=1, then there is 100% chance that Y=1 (since there are no other cards to choose from).  If X=2 then there is a 50% chance in the second step that Y=1 and 50% chance in the second step that Y=2. You get then the following table: $\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0\\ 0.25 & 0.25\end{bmatrix}$.  Restricting our attention to the first column, we see that $P(X=1|Y=1)=\frac{.5}{.5+.25}=\frac{2}{3}\neq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation with particular example is really helpful. I really appreciate it and I understand it!.